# Remove sound when clicking TabLayout

Tags: android

How do I turn off default screen tap sound when clicking tabs in tablayout. I tried `android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"` in the view itself but didn't work. On the other hand setting in the `AppTheme` disabled sounds for buttons as well.

Comment: are you putting this line in TabLayout Widget ,android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"?

Comment: You need to set it in appTheme, not only for `Button` or `TabLayout`